# OwnerDraw with WS_EX_COMPOSITED under XP

Tags: c++, winapi, doublebuffered, ownerdrawn

I have a static control which has `SS_OWNERDRAW` and `SS_NOTIFY` flag when it is crated. Its parent window has `WS_EX_COMPOSITED` flag.

Under Windows XP, it is not drawn correctly, as the picture below showed (The right-top rectangle):

[image]

But under Windows 7, it is drawn correctly, as the picture below showed (The corss "X" on right-top):

[image]

How to fix this problem in XP? Furthermore, what causes this problem (in XP)?

Comment: Post the owner-draw code. This is probably an alpha-channel mishap.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN for `CreateWindowEx()` says this:

> With WS_EX_COMPOSITED set, all descendants of a window get
>   bottom-to-top painting order using double-buffering. Bottom-to-top
>   painting order allows a descendent window to have translucency (alpha)
>   and transparency (color-key) effects, but only if the descendent
>   window also has the WS_EX_TRANSPARENT bit set. Double-buffering allows
>   the window and its descendents to be painted without flicker.

I.e. the child `STATIC` control should have `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` set.

Comment: I tried to use WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, but in XP, it then draw anything, i.e "no corss symbol, no black rectangle, just a static background there"

Comment: But in Windows 7 or 8, there is no problem.